# Mutliple spaces at the beginning of backtick not converting into space in mdx file

Tags: inline, backticks, inline-code, mdxjs

Here's my text inside a mdx file.
 `shellcraft.mips.read(0, 0xffffeeb0, 20)`
It's rendering here a expected. But on my website it's getting showed as:
`shellcraft.mips.read(0, 0xffffeeb0, 20)` I put space at the beginning of backtick. But it's not getting converted into space. How can I put space at the beginning of an inline-code? `&nbsp;` shows as it is inside backticks.